# Как вводить double с возможным/разрешённым значением Null?

Tags: c#, консоль

мне нужно разрешить пустой ввод для дальнейшей проверки.
я пробовал следующие методы, но в кжадом ошибка:

```
double? X= double?.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

double bag = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine(), ArgumentNullException);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не удалось распарсить `double`, то будет присвоено `null`.

```cs
double? number = double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out double n) ? n : (double?)null;
```

Но решение странное, `double?` в основном используют для десереализации данных, полученных извне. Для данных, полученных из консоли можно реализовать простую логику с ветвлением.

```cs
Console.Write("Введите число: ")
if (double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out double number))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Вы ввели число {number}.");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Не удалось распознать число.");
}
```

Comment: насчёт первой части пишет это - 
Error CS8400 Feature 'target-typed conditional expression' is not available in C# 8.0. Please use language version 9.0 or greater.

Comment: @СтефаноБарбато дописал решение для ранних версий шарпов

Answer (score 1):

Я бы воспользовался такой функцией:

```cs
static double? InputNumber() => Console.ReadLine() switch
{
    null => throw new EndOfStreamException("No more input lines"),
    "" => null,
    var s when double.TryParse(s, out var d) => d,
    var s => throw new FormatException($"Unrecognized value: {s}")
};
```

Обоснование: если ввод неправильный (не пустая строка и не число), имеет смысл возвращать не `null`, а строго сообщать об ошибке. Иначе неправильный ввод (например, число с неправильным десятичным разделителем) будет ошибочно распознан как валидный `null`.